# I want add item to tabcontrol with dynamic

Tags: c#, mvvm, tabcontrol

I'm making a WPF Application with MVVM pattern.

It's that I click a button many times and if I click Subbutton, it shows SubWindow with many Tabs.

Tab count is the same to click times.

But I want contain items in one Tab.

And click times is not the same always.

How should edit my code?

//view

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="CountUp" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="76" Margin="72,57,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="135" Click="OnClickCountUp"/>
    <Button Content="OpenSubWindow" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="74" Margin="269,202,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123" Click="OnClicOpenSubWindow"/>

    <Label Content="Count : " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="254,73,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="53"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding CountVal}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="307,73,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="67"/>
</Grid>
```

//ViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string count;
    public string CountVal
    {
        get { return count; }
        set
        {
            count = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CountVal");
        }

    }
    public ObservableCollection<TabItemData> TabItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<TabItemData>();


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}

public class TabItemData
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<CheckBox> Content { get; set; }
}
```

//Codebehind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private MainViewModel mViewmodel;
    int count = 0;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mViewmodel = new MainViewModel();
        this.DataContext = mViewmodel;
    }

    private void OnClicOpenSubWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 window1 = new Window1(mViewmodel);
        window1.Show();
    }

    private void OnClickCountUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        count++;

        ObservableCollection<CheckBox> items = new ObservableCollection<CheckBox>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
        {
            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
            checkBox.IsChecked = false;
            checkBox.Content = count.ToString();

            items.Add(checkBox);
        }

        mViewmodel.CountVal = count.ToString();
        mViewmodel.TabItems.Add(new TabItemData() { Header = count.ToString(), Content = items });
    }
}
```

//SubWindow's View

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Content}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

//SubWindow's Codebehind

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1(MainViewModel pMainViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = pMainViewModel;
    }
}
```

And there are supplements.

@I want use the checkbox as item in Tab. So I don't want change as possibly.

@If I can, I want add Tabs each 5 items. If you give me with that code, I'm very glad. (For Example, page1 contains item1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. page2 contains item6, 7... and so on.)

Comment: There are some things that bug me: First, you make a new TabItem each time you invoke the `OnClickCountUp` method so naturally you get more tabs.
The other thing is that we do not know what kind of object `Content` is.
I suggest it is an `ObservableCollection<CheckBox>`?
If not, I would try to instantiate a new CheckBox each time I invoked this method and if there are `Content.Count % 5 == 0`, then add a TabItem afterwards and continue creating CheckBox Items to that tab.

Comment: @Faenrig  thank you for advice! I mistaken bugs. The content object is ObsevaleCollection<CheckBox>, you are right. So I'll edit (but it takes little time). And I read your comment, I think that I must not use the ObsevaleCollection<CheckBox>. Is it correct, or you have other idea? If you give me any ideas, I'll so glad.

Comment: @Farnrig  I have edited now, could you check my code again? And I was test this code but it was not work.

Comment: @Faenrig  Sorry my reply many times. I had sloved this ploblem myself! Your comment helped me my mistakes. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad that I could help and even better you found your own solution!
Could you please write an answer an mark it as such?